# Whatsapp works with google chrome 60+ : In Ubuntu virtual machine, chromium

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu, virtual-machine, puppeteer

I am trying to create a puppeteer webscraper for whatsapp web in a ubuntu virtual machine(Azure).
This webscraper will perform some functions periodically, so first I'ill have to **Login using QR code**.
I planned to send a screenshot as a response (sendQRcode() function below) which sends **QR code screenshot** to the browser where I am calling the API so that I can scan it using mobile phone.

The issue is, it send a screenshot like this:[Screenshot of API call in a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkXgl.jpg)

So when web.whatsapp is opened in Ubuntu VM->chromium, it displays this and screenshot is taken and sent.
I need to get the screenshot of QR. (It works in my local machine).

Puppeteer code :

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({  
      executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
      headless: true });
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      const groupName = "testbot";
      await page.goto("https://web.whatsapp.com/");//https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code
      await page.setDefaultTimeout(0);

      await sendQRcode(page,res);

//After this a settimeout() function does the webscraping..
```

Send QR Function

```
async function sendQRcode(page,res)
{
  //await page.waitForSelector('[aria-label="Scan me!"]');
  const image = await page.screenshot({fullPage : true});
  res.set('Content-Type', 'image/png');
  res.send(image);
}
```

Comment: Not the main issue, but keep in mind that `await page.setDefaultTimeout(0);` can cause your script to hang forever and make it hard to debug. I'd keep the timeout to no more than a minute or two when testing, and on deploy, probably catch the error rather than risking hanging the app indefinitely until it's killed. As for the main issue, what Pupp/chrome versions are you using? Did you try upgrading as the site suggests?